# Hidden Sign out from all Google accounts in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, incognito-mode

I need to force my users to Sign out from all their Google accounts. I have a link which can do that:

https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout

And also I found a way in javascript how can I trigger this link:

```
new Image().src = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout";
```

Everything works except incognito mode and Firefox webbrowser.
The result in Web browser console is exactly the same in both situations and also it triggers that endpoint cause I can see entries in Networking which response with status 200, but I am still sign in with accounts.

Do you have any idea what might be wrong? There is no error in console. I do only receive CORS blocked but I don't care about response. I just need to make sure users are logged out before they do next actions in my website.

Do you have any other ideas how can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: well this is a fun security risk

Comment: use `window.open("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=" + encodeURIComponent(/* your own URL */))`

Comment: The problem is that at some point in application I do sign in using Google credentials and retrieve token. Next step is to open Google Takeout but the problem is when user has 2 accounts it redirects to default one which might be different then token has access to. I tried to avoid this using specific endpoint: https://takeout.google.com/u/{user email} but this returns 404 when there is only 1 account signed in

Comment: @skara9 is it possible to make redirect to localhost to test that?

Comment: I got this: https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fview3   and it returns "The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know."

Comment: never mind, has to be a valid callback - there should be a better way of doing this

Comment: document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=" + window.location.href.replaceAll("view3", "view4");     I found this but there is Redirect Notice in the middle which I need to avoid